# Xamarin.forms ListView Items not visible

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I update **xamarin.forms** From v2.0.1.6505 to v2.3.3.180 on my Droid Project,
I have the following `ListView`(simple one):

```
  customersListView = new ListView() {
                ItemsSource = customers,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(EntityViewCell)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,   
                SeparatorColor = Color.Teal            
            };
  public class EntityViewCell : ImageCell
  {
    public EntityViewCell() : base()
    {
        SetBinding(TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
        SetBinding(DetailProperty, new Binding("Description"));
        SetBinding(ImageSourceProperty, new Binding("ImageUrl"));
        TextColor = Color.Blue;        
    }
}
```

I get the following List(Items are not visible)

[image]

Why the issue occurred after I update **Xamarin.forms**?

Comment: does customers contain data?  What does EntityViewCell look like?  Try using a simple TextCell instead, if that works you know the problem is in you custom cell, if not then your data source is probably the problem.

Comment: customer contain info, i will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix solution: 
try

```
public EntityViewCell() : base()
        {
            SetBinding(TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
            SetBinding(DetailProperty, new Binding("Description"));
            SetBinding(ImageSourceProperty, new Binding("ImageUrl"));
            TextColor = Color.Blue;//or any other color         
        }
```

but maybe the issue of color contains on other pages, try to check all pages
thanks